# Paint chips: to fill or not to fill?

Tags: drywall, walls, painting, repainting, patching-drywall

I've had my flooring and skirting boards replaced recently. Ripping out the skirting boards has caused the wall paint to chip in a bunch of places, e.g.:

[image: Paint chipping]

Now my question is, should I use filler here, or just sand down the rough edge and paint? Since the plasterboard is intact it doesn't sound like filler should be needed, but the gap seems pretty big (who knew paint could be so thick??).

And if I am to use filler here, should I use fibreglass tape as well? I figure since the area is pretty big it might help me spread the filler more evenly, but it might also end up thicker than it needs to be... Help, I don't know what I'm doing :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Paint will not fill the depression or smooth out the transition. I recommend filling the depression with joint compound, no tape needed. It may take a few passes to fill it nicely, but with thin layers it will not take too long before you can apply additional coats of compound. You probably do not need to fill the entire depression, just feather the transition out. Stop when it looks good to you.

Sanding the paint edge lightly first will help you blend the two together. If you find the paint edge is flaking off the wall, scrape upward with a putty knife until you reach an area that is secure. Otherwise it may just separate on you later, undoing your repair job.

Finally, you may want to prime over the joint compound before repainting, especially if you want to try to get the match with the old area good in one coat.

Comment: 100% correct advice IMO. It may (or may not) be helpful to mention that next time you might avoid that paint "chip-out" by scoring the paint line at the top of the old skirt boards prior to removing them. Also, the application of the joint compound and associated sanding is easier if done *prior to* the installation of the new skirt boards.

Comment: Good point about removing additional paint until you find something stuck on properly.  There is a risk the whole wall is poorly adhered, at which time the whole task becomes a wall repaint :)

Comment: I would be careful with the scraping. This looks like a decent layer of compound, not just paint. At least score a small target area with a knife before scraping. This should help avoid causing a lot more to peel off than already has.

Comment: @Olivier good call - I have had exactly that issue before. Scoring can definitely help prevent you from unintentionally scraping off more than necessary.

Comment: Thanks for all the info, I'll give this a shot and see how I get on :)